# Yii2 how to handle required field one of two for two different models

Tags: php, validation, yii2, rules

I have two forms to validate for phone number and email where input fields I am generating with **\kidzen\dynamicform\DynamicFormWidget**

Phone number form rules:

```
<?php


namespace common\models\form;


    class Telephone extends someExtend
    {
        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                ['value', 'trim'],
                [['value'], 'required'],
                [['value'], 'string', 'max' => 26],
                [['value'], 'match', 'pattern' => "/^\\+?\\d{1,4}?[-.\\s]?\\(?\\d{1,3}?\\)?[-.\\s]?\\d{1,4}[-.\\s]?\\d{1,4}[-.\\s]?\\d{1,9}$/" ,
                    'message' => \Yii::t('models', 'Invalid Phone Number Format')]
            ];
        }
    }
```

Email rules:

```
<?php


namespace common\models\form;


class Email extends someExtend
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['value', 'trim'],
            [['value'], 'required'],
            [['value'], 'string', 'max' => 512],
            [['value'], 'match', 'pattern' => "/^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/",
                'message' => \Yii::t('models', 'Invalid Email Format')]
        ];
    }
}
```

they are a part of bigger form

```
<?php

namespace common\models\form;

/*  some uses */
/**
 * @property Email[] $sender_email
 * @property Telephone[] $sender_telephone
 */
class UpdateContentsForm extends Model
{
    public array $sender_email = [];
    public array $sender_telephone = [];

    public function __construct($config = [])
    {
        parent::__construct($config);
    }

    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'sender_telephone' => Yii::t('models', 'Sender Telephone'),
            'sender_email' => Yii::t('models', 'Sender Email'),
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // Rules for other fields in this form model
        ];
    }
```

On submit I call UpdateContentsForm. How can I validate that one of those two is required if in UpdateContentsForm they both are arrays from 1 - 3 elements?

If you need some more information, please feel free to ask and I will modify information shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use 'when' property of the validator

```
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                ...,
                [['value'], 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
                    // make the validation
                    if ($isValid) {
                        return true; // run the required validation
                    }
                    return false; // dont run the required validation
                }],
            ];
        }
```